# How to make my function wait before it returns another call

Tags: javascript, apex

I have a service that returns some translations. It makes a apex call which is async in nature and returns the translations. Every time I get a set of results I store the translations inside session storage and next time when a call comes I first check it inside the cached translations  and if available then I return. The problem comes when the user sends multiple  request  for translations for the same set of values. For that I am keeping a track of the apex call already in progress. However I am not sure how to make my request wait for  the previous apex call to end and return the results.

Here is the service code.

```
let labelQueue = [];
let labelMap;
let requestCustomLabels = function(labelsArr, language) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    let labelsArray = [...labelsArr];
    let returnedLabels = {};
    let cachedLabels = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("customLabels")) || {};
    labelMap = { ...cachedLabels };
    if (Object.keys(labelMap).length > 0) {
      labelsArray.forEach(item => {
        if (Object.keys(labelMap).indexOf(item) > -1) {
          labelsArray = labelsArray.filter(label => label !== item);
          //push the available lables inside returnedLabels
          returnedLabels[item] = labelMap[item];
        }
      });
    }
    if (Object.keys(returnedLabels).length === labelsArr.length) {
      resolve(returnedLabels);
    }
    if (labelQueue.length && labelsArray.length) {
      labelsArray.forEach(item => {
        if (labelQueue.indexOf(item) > -1) {
          labelsArray = labelsArray.filter(label => label !== item);
        }
      });
    }
    if (labelsArray.length) {
      // store labels to the queue
      labelsArray.forEach(label => {
        labelQueue.push(label);
      });
      // then make call to apex for the result and store it inside returnedLabels & localmap and remove them from labelsQueue
      fetchLabels(labelsArray, returnedLabels, language).then(
        labelsReturned => {
          returnedLabels = { ...returnedLabels, ...labelsReturned };
          resolve(returnedLabels);
        }
      );
    } else {
      // wait for apex to return the call;
    }
  });
};

let fetchLabels = function(labelsArray, returnedLabels, language) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    getUserProfile().then(function(userData) {
      language = language || userData.language;
      getCustomLabel(labelsArray, language)
        .then(res => {
          let labels = JSON.parse(res).data;
          for (const key in labels) {
            if (key !== "language" && key !== "totalSize") {
              //when the apex call returns remove the labels from the label Queue.
              labelQueue = labelQueue.filter(label => label !== key);
              returnedLabels[key] = labels[key];
              labelMap[key] = labels[key];
            }
          }
          // store localsMap to the storage
          sessionStorage.setItem("customLabels", JSON.stringify(labelMap));
          resolve(returnedLabels);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.error("error : ", error);
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r oops it was  a typo. Anyways the `labelsArray` will be empty  for the scenario when two requests  comes with the  same set of labels. In that case those labels will be inside the  `labelsQueue`. So I need to make that  request wait till the previous  req with same set of labels return and some how return that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually scripted this, mostly for fetching language files that are called from multiple elements on the page in a shadow dom app.

You need to:

1. Check if the promise is stored.
2. Save the ajax promise as a variable.
3. Store the variable, if it's not stored.
4. Fetch the promise, or returned the stored promise.
5. Remove the promise.

   ```
   var ajaxQueue = {};

   /**
   * @description Avoids unnecessary calls to server
   * @param {String} url The api call
   * @param {String} method 'GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'
   * @param {String} data If sending data through POST/PUT
   */
   function queueAJAXCalls(url, method, data) {
     var property = FXAjaxBehavior.getQueueProperty(url, method);

     if (firstTimeRequesting(property)) {        // 1
       var ajaxPromise = someGeneralCodeForFetchingAjaxData(url, method, data)  // 2
       .then(function(serverData) {
         removeFromAJAXQueue(property);          // 5
         return serverData;
       }).catch(function(error) {
         removeFromAJAXQueue(property);          // 5
         console.warn(error);

         return false;
       });

       storeInAJAXQueue(property, ajaxPromise);  // 3
     }

     return getAJAXFromQueue(property);          // 4
   }

   function getQueueProperty(url, method) {
     return encodeURIComponent(method + url);
   }

   function firstTimeRequesting(property) {
     return !ajaxQueue[property];
   }

   function removeFromAJAXQueue(property) {
     delete ajaxQueue[property];
   }

   function storeInAJAXQueue(property, ajaxPromise) {
     ajaxQueue[property] = ajaxPromise;
   }

   function getAJAXFromQueue(property) {
     return ajaxQueue[property];
   }
   ```

Example:

```
queueAJAXCalls('http://somedomain.com/api/fetchstuff', 'GET')
.then(function(serverResponse) {
  // do stuff, like using JSON.parse(serverResponse)
})
```

Be aware the danger with parsing the jsondata in one place, namely in `someGeneralCodeForFetchingAjaxData`, and returning arrays and objects, because that means that changing the array/object in one place will change it in all places.

Instead of implementing this, I guess you could also use a [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers).

Comment: Thanks @Rickard Elimää , for all the  help. I  implemented your solution, and it seems to work for  handling  multiple  requests. However  as I am resolving  a pending promise the  thenable of the handler function gives undefined.

Comment: What do you get when you print `serverData`? Your `fetchLabels` method is a little bit weird. You create a promise, and then inside that one you got another promise. Why don't you just return the second promise? `let fetchLabels = function(labelsArray, returnedLabels, language) {
  return getUserProfile()...`